# unable to see new Git commit after checking out earlier commits

Tags: git

I made a git commit, VCS and then i checked out other earlier from the log. I'm unable to find the new git commit to checkout.
I lost all my changes and unable to traverse back to the newest commit

Comment: Have you tried `git checkout HEAD`? Anyway, if you are new to git I suggest also to use a GUI like SourceTree or GitKraken

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

As long as you made your commit on a branch, you just need to use `git checkout branch` now.

If you made your commit in *detached HEAD* mode, you must find its hash ID.  It's wise to give that hash ID a human-readable name, perhaps a branch name, afterward.  You can use `git reflog` to help you find the lost hash ID.

#### Long

Note that I have added a few words to your question here.  This specificity is important.

> ... and then I checked out [an]other earlier [commit] from the log [i.e., using the raw hash ID displayed by `git log`, I ran `git checkout a123456...` or similar].  I'm unable to find the new git commit['s hash ID] to checkout. I lost all my changes and unable to traverse back to the newest commit

As you now know, a Git hash ID is the unique name that Git uses to find each commit.  That is, every Git commit has some big ugly string of letters and digits that Git uses to locate that commit:

```
git checkout 5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7
```

for instance, finds that commit (assuming it exists—it's a commit in the Git repository for Git, so it's probably not in your own repository) and extracts its contents into a form we can work with.

You also know that each commit contains a full and complete snapshot of your source code.  Each commit also has some *metadata*, data about the commit, such as your name (or the name of whoever made that commit), an email address, and so on.  What you might not know is that each commit also stores the hash ID of its *parent* (previous or predecessor) commit.  For instance, the parent of the commit whose hash ID I used above is a commit whose hash ID starts with `b5796d9a`.

When you run `git log`, the default for Git is to start out showing you the *current* commit—the one you have checked out.  Then Git uses that commit's saved parent ID, so as to show you the commit that came before that one.  That parent has another parent, so after showing you the parent, Git moves on to the grandparent, and so on.  That's why you cannot see your *latest* commit: you're starting at an old commit, and moving backwards from there.

That's the first key to using Git: **Git works backwards.**  It must start at the end and move towards the beginning.  But it actually starts at whatever frozen-point-in-time you chose, so to get back to "now", you need to do something different.

Note that Git remembers which commit is the *current* commit using a mechanism that Git calls `HEAD` (spelled in all capitals like this, though you can use the symbol `@` if you prefer).  So below, when we keep mentioning `HEAD`, remember that this is Git's way of remembering *the commit you have out right now*.

#### Branch and tag names

As you have just seen, hash IDs are not very human friendly.  As a result, we generally do not use them much, at least not directly, and Git does not *force* us to use them.  Instead, Git offers us the ability to link human-readable names to various commits.  The most important kind of name is a *branch name*, but it's perhaps simpler to start by illustrating a *tag name* instead, because branch names have several special properties.

A *tag name* is just a human-readable name for a commit.  For instance, in the Git repository for Git, the tag name `v2.20.0` identifies the commit that the maintainers have designated "Git 2.20".  Therefore, the name `v2.20.0` has the same function as the big ugly `5d826e9729...` thing.  So instead of:

```
git checkout 5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7
```

I can do:

```
git checkout v2.20.0
```

The end result is exactly the same: I wind up with Git version 2.20 (2.20.0, to be exact) checked-out.

If I do this, I get what Git calls a *detached HEAD:*

```
$ git checkout v2.20.0
Note: checking out 'v2.20.0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 5d826e9729 Git 2.20
```

The reason Git printed all of the above out is that people new to Git forget that this produces a detached HEAD and that detached HEADs can be kind of painful, if you do forget.

To exit this detached HEAD mode, I can just `git checkout master` to go back to the `master` branch:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

and now all is sensible again.

#### Branch names are special

Branch names, like tag names, identify some particular commit:

```
$ git rev-parse master
5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7
```

Here's that same hash ID yet again.  But there are key differences between a branch name and any *other* way of naming a commit, like `v2.20.0` or `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7`.  In particular, when you use `git checkout` with a raw hash ID or with a tag name, Git stores the actual commit hash ID directly in `HEAD`.  That's this detached HEAD mode we just saw.

Once you are in this mode, the *only* place that Git has, for finding the current hash ID, is the special name `HEAD`.  Every time you use `git checkout` with some other commit, that overwrites the hash ID that Git had stuck into `HEAD` earlier.  And, since Git works *backwards*, it's only easy to go *backwards* from here—it's very hard to go forwards!

But when you give `git checkout` a *branch name* like `master`, Git does something quite different.  Instead of setting up its `HEAD` to remember a raw hash ID, Git sets its `HEAD` to remember the *branch name itself*:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

So now you're `on branch master`, as `git status` puts it.  Git doesn't remember the hash ID directly, but rather, remembers the fact that you're on this branch.  Meanwhile the *branch name* remembers the commit hash.  So `HEAD` is attached to the name, and the name has the hash ID.

If you now make a *new* commit, what Git does at this point is particularly clever.  Git builds the new commit as usual, using the current commit's hash ID as the new commit's parent.  Then, once the new commit is all done and has its big ugly hash ID assigned to it, Git writes the new commit's hash ID *into* the *name* `master`, which is the name to which `HEAD` is attached.

We can draw this as a picture, although it helps a lot of replace the big ugly hash IDs with single letters.  Let's say we're on a commit whose hash ID is `H`, and its parent has hash ID `G`, whose parent is `F`, and so on.  We say that each commit *points to* its parent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

The *branch name* `master` holds `H`'s hash ID, so `master` itself points to `H`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

Finally, `HEAD` is *attached to* `master`, so that if there are multiple branch names, Git knows which one to use:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

So if we now make our new commit, it gets assigned a new hash ID—I'll use the next letter, `L`, here—and it points back to `H`, and then Git overwrites the name `master` so that it points to `L`:

```
...--F--G--H--L   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

So this is the second key to using Git: **branch names move.**  A branch name holds the hash ID of the *last* commit on the branch.  Making a *new* commit, while you have some particular branch checked out—while your `HEAD` is attached to that branch name—*automatically* moves the branch name.

Since your `HEAD` is attached to the branch name, and the branch name now identifies the *new* last commit, `git log` will start at commit `L` and work backwards, showing you `L`, then `H`, then `G`, and so on.

#### This is why detached HEADs are a bit painful

Suppose that you have the original sequence above, but you use `git checkout` with a raw hash ID to select historic commit `G`.  To make things fit we need to push `H` up a bit:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G   <-- HEAD
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Now let's make a new commit `L`:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G--L   <-- HEAD
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Note that the *only* name for new commit `L` is `HEAD`.  Now let's use `git checkout` to *move* our `HEAD` somewhere else, or re-attach it.  For instance, let's just re-attach it to `master`:

```
          H   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G--L
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

The `git log` command will now start at commit `H` and work backwards, showing us `H`, then `G`, then `F`, and so on as usual.

If we have not saved (written down, or in scrollback in a terminal window, or whatever) the hash ID of commit `L`, how will we ever find this commit again?

#### This is where reflogs come in

To help rescue us from mistakes, Git stores a log of the *previous values* of each of these various names.  That is, if `master` pointed to `G` at some point—before we made `H`—and then we made `H`, `master` now points to `H`, but it *used to* point to `G`, so Git keeps a reflog entry, spelled `master@{1}`, to remember that `master` once pointed to `G`.

Git does the same with the special name `HEAD`.  Every time we check out some new commit, Git updates the `HEAD` reflog.  We can view this reflog with `git reflog`, which defaults to showing the reflog for `HEAD`:

```
$ git reflog
5d826e9729 (HEAD -> master, tag: v2.20.0, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7 to master
5d826e9729 (HEAD -> master, tag: v2.20.0, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to v2.20.0
```

In this case, the first two reflog entries are not especially interesting since both are for the last commit on `master`.  But if you made a commit like `L` in our illustration above, and now need to find its hash ID, `git reflog` can be quite helpful.

#### Giving a new branch name to an existing commit

Suppose that you did in fact make `L` like this, and have lost it:

```
          H   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G--L
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Then you use `git reflog` to find it, and you do find it.  You can now check it out:

```
git checkout llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
```

(use the actual hash ID, of course).  You will now be in "detached HEAD" mode, and now it's time for the advice that `git checkout` itself prints when you first enter this detached HEAD mode.  It said we can use `git checkout -b`:

```
git checkout -b xyz-branch
```

for instance.

What this does is to *create* a *new* branch name, pointing to the current (i.e., `HEAD`) commit, and then immediately attach `HEAD` to that commit.  So now we have:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G--L   <-- xyz-branch (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop
```

Now we're all set, because we have a *human-readable name* ("xyz-branch") for the *last* commit on this new branch.  Every time we add a new commit by checking out the branch, doing some work, and committing it, Git will automatically update the new branch name.